# DatePicker SelectedDate string format

Tags: wpf, datepicker, string-formatting

I have derived the DatePicker class to support an additional DateMode property which will allow the user to use the control only as per the DateMode (Day, Month, Year). So if the DateMode is set to Year, the control will not be able further drill down to see months of the year and then further to days of the month.
The control is working good, but for one problem. Though I have applied string formatting on the 'PART_TextBox' control from the DatePicker template, which will change the formatting based on the DateMode, as soon the DatePicker control loses focus the formatting is lost. Following is my derived DatePicker control code:

```
public class MyDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    public string DateMode
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DateModeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DateModeProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DateMode.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DateModeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DateMode", typeof(string), typeof(MyDatePicker), new UIPropertyMetadata("Day"));

    protected override void OnCalendarOpened(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = this.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", this) as Popup;
        var tb = this.Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", this) as TextBox;

        if (popup != null && popup.Child is System.Windows.Controls.Calendar)
        {
            if (DateMode == "Year")
                ((System.Windows.Controls.Calendar)popup.Child).DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Decade;
            else if (DateMode == "Month")
                ((System.Windows.Controls.Calendar)popup.Child).DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year;
            else if (DateMode == "Day")
                ((System.Windows.Controls.Calendar)popup.Child).DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Month;
        }
        ((System.Windows.Controls.Calendar)popup.Child).DisplayModeChanged += new EventHandler<CalendarModeChangedEventArgs>(DatePickerCo_DisplayModeChanged);
    }

    protected override void OnCalendarClosed(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCalendarClosed(e);
        IsDropDownOpen = false;
        var popup = this.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", this) as Popup;
        ((System.Windows.Controls.Calendar)popup.Child).DisplayModeChanged -= new EventHandler<CalendarModeChangedEventArgs>(DatePickerCo_DisplayModeChanged);
    }

    private void DatePickerCo_DisplayModeChanged(object sender, CalendarModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = this.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", this) as Popup;
        var tb = this.Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", this) as TextBox;

        if (popup != null && popup.Child is System.Windows.Controls.Calendar)
        {
            var _calendar = popup.Child as System.Windows.Controls.Calendar;

            if (DateMode == "Month" && _calendar.DisplayMode == CalendarMode.Month)
            {
                if (IsDropDownOpen)
                {
                    this.SelectedDate = _calendar.DisplayDate;
                    this.IsDropDownOpen = false;
                    _calendar.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year;
                }
                tb.Text = this.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("MMM yyyy");
            }
            else if (DateMode == "Year" && _calendar.DisplayMode == CalendarMode.Year)
            {
                if (IsDropDownOpen)
                {
                    this.SelectedDate = _calendar.DisplayDate;
                    this.IsDropDownOpen = false;
                    _calendar.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Decade;
                }
                tb.Text = this.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably getting interference with the base class. I'm not sure of the exact setup but I think `PART_TextBox` has a Binding that's set by the `DatePicker` and is probably updating on LostFocus and looping back to clear out the `Text` value that you had set directly. You might try using `BindingOperations.GetBinding` to access the binding on `Text` and modify it's StringFormat instead of setting `Text` directly.